# Ways for making a Scala script standalone in Linux?

Tags: scripting, shebang

*Programming Scala* says:

> Invoking scripts with scala is tedious when you use these scripts
>   frequently. On Windows and Unix-like systems, you can create
>   standalone Scala scripts that don’t require you to use the scala
>   script-file-name invocation. For Unix-like systems, the following
>   example demonstrates how to make an executable script. Remember that
>   you have to make the permissions executable, e.g., chmod +x secho:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # src/main/scala/progscala2/toolslibs/secho
> exec scala "$0" "$@"
> !#
> print("You entered: ")
> args.toList foreach { s => printf("%s ", s) }
> println
> ```
>
> Here is how you might use it:
>
> ```
> $ secho Hello World
> You entered: Hello World
> ```

I was wondering what it means by

```
# src/main/scala/progscala2/toolslibs/secho
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
```

in `sh`?

Can I make a Scala script standalone as

```
#!/path/to/scala
print("You entered: ")
args.toList foreach { s => printf("%s ", s) }
println
```

on Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sh`,

```
# src/main/scala/progscala2/toolslibs/secho
```

is a comment, ignored;

```
exec scala "$0" "$@"
```

causes the current process to replace itself with `scala`, and all the shell parameters as arguments;

```
!#
```

has no effect because the shell has stopped reading the script at this point.

However Scala handles script files by ignoring a “header” at the start of the file; that header starts at a line beginning with `#!` (or `::#!` on Windows) and ends with a line [matching either `!#` (`::!#`) or `/env`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/c8249b35f6000bb606906850e421a29f14b15010/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/SourceFile.scala#L92). The header can be a single line, so both

```scala
#!/path/to/scala
!#
print("You entered: ")
args.toList foreach { s => printf("%s ", s) }
println
```

and

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env scala
print("You entered: ")
args.toList foreach { s => printf("%s ", s) }
println
```

work (the latter requires `scala` to be on the `PATH`). The latter corresponds to [the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/your-first-lines-of-scala.html#script-it).

(`!#` is the symmetric of `#!`, and is used in Scala to close the “header” opened by `#!`, in a fashion similar to `/*` and `*/` for comments in C.)

Comment: Thanks. What does `!#` mean?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: (1) I just happened to see that some said `!#` is a shell feature not related to Scala http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-shell-script-example-exec-syntax.  (2) `${!#}
means final positional parameter` http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html, but here it is `!#`, not sure if these two are related. (3) As youre reply says, there seems to be two ways  writing a Scala script. Are both equivalent? when to use which, if you happen to know.

Comment: (1) The author of that post is learning as he writes, “I didn't know what the "!#" characters are for” etc. The error message he mentions is output by `scala`, not by the shell. (2) No, they are not related. The shell isn’t involved at all in handling `!#`, it stops running before it gets to that line. (3) Given that the latter form works now, and is simpler, you might as well use that. Presumably older versions of Scala don’t support it, which is why the first form exists; but instead of looking at old docs, look at the current Scala docs, which refer to the simpler form.

Comment: Thanks. I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365436/choose-interpreter-after-script-start-e-g-if-else-inside-hashbang/365447#comment648996_365447. I also don't  find `!#` in scala language specification https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/doc/scala-documentation/ScalaReference.pdf

Comment: Is the complication specific to Scala or common to other languages?

Comment: It applies to any language where you want to support a shebang but “#” doesn’t introduce comments.

Comment: (1) Do you mean Scala compiler/interpreter  does not treat `#!/path/to/scala` as a comment? Why does `#!/usr/bin/env scala` work then? 
(2) Is `!#` used specifically for Scala or not specific to any language? (I don't find it in Scala language specification, and suspect it is not specific to any language.)

Comment: (1) See the update, `/usr/bin/env` (or rather, `/env`) is handled specifically. (2) `!#` is specific to Scala, although since it’s the symmetric of `!#` it’s possible other languages use a similar approach.